# Travis deploy stage not running with condition if: branch = master AND tag IS present AND type = push

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

My Travis file contains two stages:

- `test`, which runs build/test for multiple Node.js versions (and works)
- `deploy`, which should run build and deploy the code to npm when the following condition is met: `branch = master AND tag IS present AND type = push`

I pushed a [tagged commit](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/commit/d28d339ac6a5b682eb8be2d4e7a5fb061f1934c8) to the master (so all three conditions should be met), but after the `test` stage finishes successfully, the `deploy` stage [is not started](https://travis-ci.org/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/builds/499874029).

Here are other (potentially important) parts of my [`.travis.yml` file](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/blob/4229f6e6e3fe5eafe611b3ab71f5aa8899b3b8e7/.travis.yml):

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - '8'
  - '9'
  - '10'
  #- '11' # Runs the coverage report (added below)

before_script: npm run build
script:
  - npm run lint
  - npm run coverage

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
      node_js: '11'
      after_success: 'cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js'
    - stage: deploy
      node_js: '11'
      script: skip
      deploy:
        provider: npm
        # ...

stages:
  - test
  - name: deploy
    if: branch = master AND tag IS present AND type = push
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out myself after adding these lines to my travis file:

```
echo "$TRAVIS_EVENT_TYPE" # result: push
echo "$TRAVIS_TAG"        # result: v0.14.0
echo "$TRAVIS_BRANCH"     # result: v0.14.0
```

So the branch is set to the tag name, when a tag is set. I also found this hint on the [docs for environment variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables):

> Note that for tags, git does not store the branch from which a commit was tagged.

Strangely, you can still check for the branch in the deploy condition. So this worked for me:

```
  # ...
  deploy:
    provider: npm
    # ...
    on:
      tags: true
      branch: master

stages:
  - test
  - name: deploy
    if: type = push
```